# "bis" on an address

Tags: vocabulaire, usage

In "boulevard Pereire 190 bis" (written in 1911), what does "bis" mean?  To me, in other contexts, it means "repeat" but that doesn't make sense here.

Comment: It is used not only with buildings - e.g., on autoroutes one sometimes encounters*"itinéraire bis"* - an alternative/secondary route to the same destination. *Numérobis* is a wordplay on *bis* and typical sound of ancient Egyptian names (architect in "Asterix&Obelix: Mission Cléopâtre").

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That means that there used to be a single address here but the property has been split in two so there is now *190 boulevard Pereire* and *190 bis boulevard Pereire*. *Bis* is Latin for twice.

You can have a third address which would be called *190 ter* ("thrice"). Much rarer would be a fourth one : *190 quater*, and even rarer a fifth one: *190 quinquies*.

Technically, Latin numerals could be used for whatever subdivision like *sexies*, *septies* and so on.

This scheme is also used in Spain and occasionaly elsewhere (see [House_numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_numbering)).

French Law also use this Latin numbering. When a new article, chapter, section, etc. is to be inserted between two existing ones, a Latin suffix will allow to distinguish it.

e.g.:

> Article 1
> **Article 1 *bis***  <- new article
> Article 2

French Senate [real examples](https://www.assemblee-nationale.fr/dyn/16/textes/l16b0443_projet-loi):

6th:

[image: sexies]

14th:

[image: quaterdecies]

Comment: So it is SORT OF like "apartment two" ?

Comment: @WGroleau It is not used for appartement numbering, only for building numbering.  France is not the only country to use this system. You will find more info in the wikipedia article on [house numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_numbering).

Comment: Exactly. I have never seen quaters and quinquies though (although I'm sure they exist), have you? ;)

Comment: @Thinkr A plot next to mine that was on a *ter* number. It was split in two and a house was built on the free part. My new neighbors's address is *quater*.

Comment: @jlliagre Wow. I never saw quaters or quinquies. But maybe I wasn't looking for them? :P

Comment: @Thinkr I have yet to see a *sexies* number, I wonder if people would object about it ;-)

Comment: I have a feeling all this is no help now. My house used to be (up till last year, and number  plaque provided by commune) 3. Couple of months ago, a new plaque arrived - 437. Wondered where all the other houses were to be built (there's only 2 in our lane) but it turns out the number system revolves round how many metres the house is from the main road!!! For the pompiers - just look for the smoke! No need to get out the measuring tape, surely! In the bigband, song xxx 'bis' is the 2nd version of song xxx.

Comment: @Tim Yes they did the same here (somewhere in France between Lyon and Marseille ;-), a bit disconcerting for folks not used to it.

Comment: @Frank Unlike the sequential street numbering, road numbering is more likely to use the distance system. It is certainly more convenient, especially when the road is a long one.

Comment: @jlliagre I'm used to many different styles of street, road numbering... Japan uses a "concentric" system that doesn't rely on distance and is unlike what you can see in France :-) But all those systems work quite well, as far as I can tell...

Comment: In the US we usually append a letter, so "190 Pereire Blvd" gets split into "190A Pereire Blvd" and "190B Pereire Blvd". Or sometimes it's 190-1 and 190-2.

Comment: @Barmar The suffixes A, B, C... are also used here, not when a plot is divided in isolated parts but when a complex is built on a plot with each letter corresponding to a separate entrance.

Comment: The US also has addresses with a "half" in them, so you'd get "190 1/2 Pereire Blvd".

Comment: @MichaelLugo Addresses are not usually translated. Sometimes, they are explained...

Comment: @MichaelLugo That sounds King's Crossesque :-)